# What are the effects of teacher job share on pupil attainment?

Tags: primary-schooler, teaching, middle-childhood

What are the effects of teacher job share on pupil attainment, at UK primary school level (age approx 4 to 11)?

In the UK, most pupils have a single teacher for all subjects at this age (rather than subject-specialist teachers) but flexible working practices sometimes permit two teachers to job-share, usually on a basis of 2 days one teacher / 3 days another teacher. Both teachers would still usually be teaching all core subjects.

I am looking for references or studies rather than anecdotal experience.

Comment: I'm also intrigued that it works that way in the UK.  At least for me, as early as 3rd grade (8-9 yo) I had separate teachers for the major subjects (initially reading and math).

Comment: I want to add too that it mostly is that way in the US, and it puzzles me. I grew up in Denmark, and at every grade past kindergarten we had different teachers in different subjects. We had the same math teacher from 1st through 9th grade for instance, which build a great relationship. I would worry just one teacher would not have the expertise - even just different perspectives are good for the kids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site seems to have a relevant article but it requires registration to view it:
http://www.usethekey.org.uk/curriculum-and-learning/developing-teacher-practice/teachers-job-sharing-how-effective-is-it-for-pupils#section-2

Edit: here is the paper without registration:
http://www.teachers.org.uk/files/job-sharing-nut-guidance-jan-2012.doc

> "There is no evidence that splitting responsibility for classes in any
>   way affects pupils’ education.  OFSTED concluded in a 1994 research
>   report that the quality of work of part-time teachers, including job
>   sharers, was “significantly above the national average”.  In its
>   reports on individual schools OFSTED has commented favourably on the
>   benefits of job share arrangements, including the quality of
>   educational provision and the good progress made by pupils taught by
>   job sharers.  In addition, employment tribunals have rejected any
>   assumption that job sharing has an adverse effect on education."